# Latest MiKTeX-Update broke XeLaTeX with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, expl3

I updated MiKTeX a few days ago and since then I cannot compile XeLaTeX with fontspec anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it MiKTeX tells me that it `expl3` is an unknown package. I cannot find this package in the Package Manager. Without the `\usepackage{fontspec}` the file compiles fine.

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There has been a passing issue with way MiKTeX installs LaTeX3 support. Use the MiKTeX Package Manager to install the `l3kernel` and `l3packages` bundles, and at the same time remove `expl3` and `xpackages` if they are installed.

Comment: Thanks, that solved this issue.  
Where can someone find such information? MiKTeX Homepage seems to not state anything about this...

Comment: Thank you very mach! I agree with jayeff: it's 20/aug and I have have spent some time searching for the solution until I fixed the problem with your answer, something shoud be made by the MiKTeX folks! =)

Comment: Same here. Thank God I found this Q+A. Without TeX.SX I'd probably spent hours on looking for the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph Wright: The fontspec and the latest l3kernel seems to be
inconsistent:

`! Undefined control sequence.`
`<recently read> \str_case:nnn`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Will knows about this: I'll prod him to get the release out for a `fontspec` update.