# XeTeX compiling

Tags: xetex, compiling

How can I create a PDF file from .tex file using `xetex.exe`?

What should I enter to console? I tried different combinations like `xetex -pdf filepath` and so but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `xetex.exe /?` or `xetex.exe /h`.

Comment: perhaps pdfxetex.exe? like pdflatex.exe is needed instead of latex.exe for producing pdf output. (though you didn't tell us, i assume you are using miktex distribution)

Comment: Typing `xetex story-zapfino.tex` in the shell produced a PDF file for me on Max OSX with TeXLive2011. I don't use `xetex` (had to download a file from http://www.tug.org/mactex/src/Demos/XeTeX-showcase/) so not likely that i have any settings specific to this.

Comment: I wrote **xelatex filename** but then I got the following error **1.52 \char_make_active:n{"20}%** and I couldn't find anything helpful on Int

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from StackOverflow. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This is more of a comment on the original question, or perhaps an edit to the question, than an answer. After a suitable delay I'll remove it from public view. WE could do with a minimal example, but I suspect you've loaded `fontspec` and have mis-matched versions of the necessary support packages. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/latest-miktex-update-broke-xelatex-with-fontspec

Comment: But this link did not solve my problem I have installed both packages mentioned there and still get this message :(

Comment: As I said, please register here and edit into your question a minimal example. A copy of the log file you get would also be very useful.

Answer (score 10):

XeTeX automatically outputs PDF (usually) so don’t enter any extra arguments. Try `xetex foo` for a TeX document, and `xelatex foo` for a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 2):

Try `xelatex`... highly likely, you don't have a `tex` file but you do have a `latex` file.