# Trying to typset Persian(Farsi) with MikTeX - expl3.sty not found

Tags: errors, miktex, languages, expl3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Latest MiKTeX-Update broke XeLaTeX with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/latest-miktex-update-broke-xelatex-with-fontspec)

I am a new user of LaTeX. I have installed MikTeX 2.9 and my editor is: TeXnic. Actually, I installed the `xepersian` package with the MikTex package manager. However, when I enclose `\usepackage{xepersian}` I get this error: `File 'expl3.sty' not found!` What is my problem? Can you help me please?

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/latest-miktex-update-broke-xelatex-with-fontspec to me

Comment: My guess is that you have the "TeXnicCenter disturbs the on-the-fly-installation"-problem. Compile your document once from the command line or with texworks instead of TeXnicCenter.