# OTF fonts with Miktex

Tags: fonts

This is my code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill-Roman}
\begin{document}
This is a text.
\textit{Here goes!}
\end{document}
```

I have updated the admin package manager successfully, but it still doesn't work:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:\Users\Guillaume\Desktop\Medlye\Brill roman essai.tex"
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\Guillaume\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xgreek\expl3\l3names.sty")

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 48, version
               `2011/12/30' of package l3names,
               but only version
               `1998/04/20 v2.0b L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitiv
es'
               is available.


! Package expl3 Error: MismatchedLaTeX3packagesdetected..

See the expl3 package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59   }
```

Comment: You have mismatched versions of `fontspec` and `expl3`. As you use MiKTeX, use the package manger to make sure that `l3kernel` and `l3packages` are installed, and remove `expl3` and `xpackages` if they are installed.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/latest-miktex-update-broke-xelatex-with-fontspec

Comment: what do you mean by "xpackages"?

Comment: In the past, the LaTeX3 code was packaged in MiKTeX as `expl3` and `xpackages`. We altered this some time ago to `l3kernel` and `l3packages`, but sometimes you have to remove the older versions by hand.

Comment: l3kernel and l3packages are installed but not on the Admin package manager, where I get a Windows error 87 message. What should I do? expl3 is not in the list, so I got rid of it manually, it was on my computer. There are no "xpackages".

Comment: First run the package manager as Admin, and remove (if present) `expl3` and `xpackages`. Then run the package manager _without_ Admin and do the same.

Comment: They aren't present on either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3769/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-guillaume-coatalen)

Comment: I was telling you that both managers haven't got either expl3 or xpackages

Comment: Guillaume the packages are now called l3packages, l3kernel and l3experimental. I doubt that the problem mentioned by Joseph still persist. Probably you simply didn't update properly. Synchronize in the package manager the repository. Then run the update manager. If you have a multiuser installation do both in admin and user mode. If the problem persist: show your log file so that we can see the actual pathes and versions used.

Comment: When I try to synchronize, it says permission denied

Comment: The other problem being that I cannot find the update wizard.

Comment: @Guillaume: Your miktex version, your windows version, if you used the package manager in admin or user mode, where you looked for the update manager, which repository you  normally use, the exact wording of an error are all things that matter. Don't let us drag every information piecewise out of you.

Comment: Sorry about all this, I've have finally manage to update the manager.

Comment: LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 48, version
               `2011/12/30' of package l3names,
               but only version
               `1998/04/20 v2.0b L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitiv
es'
               is available.


! Package expl3 Error: MismatchedLaTeX3packagesdetected..

See the expl3 package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.59   }

Comment: I wrote: show the log-file. This is not the same as the terminal output. Only the log-file also mentions the versions of packages. In any case your system obviously finds an old l3names.sty in the xgreek package. Deinstall and reinstall this xgreek package. And really make sure that you update your system in admin *and* user mode.

Comment: There are no updates available:

Comment: This is my code, I run the ltx file with xelatex:

Comment: %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\begin{document}
This is a text.
\textit{Here goes!}
\end{document}

Comment: And these are the errors warnings I get

expl3.sty
59
Package expl3 Error: MismatchedLaTeX3packagesdetected..

See the expl3 package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.59   }

expl3.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 48, version               `2011/12/30' of package l3names,               but only version               `1998/04/20 v2.0b L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitives'               is available.