# Latest MiKTex update breaks with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm using this document class type https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex/blob/master/tudelft-report.cls and I get the following error when I run it throgh XeLatex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \str_case:nnn 

l.72     ]{BookmanOldStyle}
```

I read and tried what the following post suggests ([Latest MiKTeX-Update broke XeLaTeX with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/latest-miktex-update-broke-xelatex-with-fontspec)), but I still have no solution. The font files are in the right path and installed.

It was working perfectly last week, but reinstalled MikTex and started having this issue.

Any idea about what is happening?

The code I'm running is

```
\ifxetex
    %% If the document is compiled with XeLaTeX, we load the TU Delft house
    %% style fonts: Bookman Old Style (serif) for titles and Tahoma (sans-serif)
    %% for text. Even if the nativefonts option was specified, we need these
    %% fonts for the cover.
\newfontfamily\tudrmfamily[
    Path = fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]{BookmanOldStyle}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the line of code (on or close to line 72) that contains `BookmanOldStyle` as a (substring)?

Comment: @Mico That seems to be in the class: https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex/blob/master/tudelft-report.cls#L72

Comment: @Mico yes, the code is on that link. I'll edit anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem. As Joseph Wright wrote on the miktex mailing list:

> Will Robertson knows about this and it will be fixed soon. For the
>   present
>
> ```
>  \usepackage{expl3}
>  \ExplSyntaxOn
>  \cs_new_eq:NN \str_case:nnn \str_case:nnF
>  \cs_new_eq:NN \str_case_x:nnn \str_case_x:nnF
>  \cs_new_eq:NN \int_case:nnn \int_case:nnF
>  \ExplSyntaxOff
>  \usepackage{fontspec}
> ```
>
> Hopefully this will only be needed for a few days.

Comment: Okey perfect, I missed that...hope is fixed soon!

Comment: @YuSemanuel Fix went to CTAN yesterday. Give them a chance to get back from the TUG meeting and install it :-)

Comment: Now the fontspec error is fixed but i get this one: 
`("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math-table.t
ex")))
! Undefined control sequence.
\um_set_mathsymbol:nNNn #1#2#3#4->\tl_case:Nnn 
                                               #3{\mathop {\um_set_big_opera...
l.137     ]{CambriaMath}
                        
? `

Comment: Add `\cs_set_eq:NN\tl_case:Nnn\tl_case:NnF` until unicode-math is updated.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, where do I add that?

Comment: Use your brain and look at the code in my answer.

Comment: yep sorry, I'm a bit overloaded now