# ! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined" ! ! Control sequence \str_case:nnn undefined

Tags: pdftex

I am starting to write a report and I have used what I have previously done some months ago and it gives me this error:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"

!
! Control sequence \str_case:nnn undefined.

! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
```

even if I only have the first page and eliminate the rest it still gives me the same error.

On the contrary, on other complete reports it compiles without errors.

Without the packages the main document is this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\pagestyle{empty}
 PHYSICS DEPARTMENT\\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[center,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontes para caracteres nao ingleses
\usepackage{ae, aecompl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=3.17cm, bottom=3.17cm, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
```

I updated all the packages of miktex.

I am using windows 8.1, texmaker 4.4.1 and miktex 2.9.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We will need to see your preamble. This is likely due to a passing issue with `fontspec` but I can't be sure.

Comment: the preamble is \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's what we need to see

Comment: Ok I detected that the problem was with this line:

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} The preamble is now on the question

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256656/latest-miktex-update-breaks-with-fontspec: fix is the same. I'll try to get `mhchem` sorted (I was actually in the same place as Will so `fontspec` was easy).

Comment: @JosephWright when moving to Linux it gives me errors when compiling the lines which I added to solve the problem in Windows: _! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
!
! Control sequence \str_case_x:nnn already defined.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information_