# \setmainfont error with most recent fontspec version

Tags: fontspec

I get a mysterious error running the following MWE (with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

The error description in the `.log` file reads:

```
...
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2245.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \str_case:nnF 

l.5 \setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
...
```

And the document that's produced looks like this:
[image]

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 with a very recent version of fontspec, which according to MiKTeX's Update Manager was packaged only four days ago (`2015-07-214`).

Is this a bug?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256656/73

Comment: @JosephWright: That here is the other way round: fontspec is too new and `\str_case:nnF ` is unknown. Einbandi: Update the l3-packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I just updated all the l3-related packages I could find but unfortunately the problem persits.

Comment: Did you run the update manager in admin *and* user mode?

Comment: So far only in admin mode. I'm running in user mode right now and will get back to you.

Comment: After running the Update Manager in both admin *and* user mode the problem is now fixed. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, a relatively ancient `expl3`