# Missing \begin{document} in .cls file

Tags: xetex, fontspec, texlipse

I am using the template `deedy resume`.  Here is my [repo](https://github.com/DKuether/Resume) with my resume.  I am getting an error in compilation.  I have checked for BOM characters. I have reinstalled texlive-full.  I am at a lost for this.

*I would post more links but do not have enough reputation.

**EDIT 1:**
Repo edited to MWE_document.tex and MWE_deedy-resume-openfont.cls to reduce code, addressing a comment.

My [log file](https://github.com/DKuether/Resume/blob/master/tmp/document.log)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Most times this is caused by some typesetting character or a typesetting command before `\begin[document}`.

Comment: `l.29 ...lor=primary, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}` is the first error. Try to reduce your file to the minimum one with the error (called a MWE, Minimal Working Example) and post it in your question. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Unsure if related but the log file reports that the `expl3` - macro `\str_case:nnn` is unknown. As far as I know there's indeed no such macro

Comment: I've just downloaded the repo and compiled both `document.tex` and `temp-document.tex` -- without errors. Have you really updated your TeXLive distribution?

Comment: I had no problem compiling with `xelatex`. The `lato` font is installed on my Windows 7 system (in C:\Windows\Fonts).

Comment: Have you pushed the changes? There's no MWE_document.tex so far

Comment: Just did now.  Problem is resolved now.  Though I would like to resolve that conflict so I can work on both projects without removing the packages.

Comment: The problem is: It's not clear what your real problem is? Outdated distro? Perhaps! But why can't you work on both projects? Unclear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big Thanks to all the comments. @Christian Hupfer comment pointed out something very strange.  Those files were indexed with texhash for use in of media in a beamer project.  I removed those files and ran texhash and the problem was resolved.  I imagine that the l3 experimental files had some sore of conflict with the fontspec package.

**EDIT 1:**
[Here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3experimental?lang=en) is the link to the package causing the conflict for reference.

Comment: Using @ does not work in an regular post ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in `expl3`. Update your TeX distribution or read the answer to
[Latest MiKTex update breaks with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256656/latest-miktex-update-break)