# Chemical packages bug fontspec mhchem siunits

Tags: etoolbox, mhchem, siunits

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\chemname[2ex]{\chemfig{H-[, 0.5]C(-[2, 0.5]H)(-[6, 0.5]H)-C(=[1]O)(-[7]O-[,,,,red]H)}}{\textcolor{red}{ethanoic acid}} \chemsign{+} \chemname[2ex]{\chemfig{H-[, 0.5]C(-[2, 0.7]H)(-[6, 0.5]H)-C(-[2, 0.5]H)(-[6, 0.5]H)(-O-[,,,,blue]H)}}{\textcolor{blue}{ethanol}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf

Error:

```
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \regex_match:NnTF undefined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.53 ...nerate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF { NV }

?
```

From other web page:[Latest MiKTex update breaks with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256656/latest-miktex-update-breaks-with-fontspec#)

Tried and received same error.

System: Debian 9. Packages are installed manually; tlgr is *not* used.

What and how to remove, to revert to previous installation?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! I do not reproduce this error on my TeXLive 2020 installation. However, I get a complaint that `\chemsign` is undefined.

Comment: you are using files from two locations: /usr/local/share/texmf and /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist. Quite probably this means that you have outdated versions. You should better clean this up. And you are not using fontspec so the title of your question is wrong.

Comment: this looks more like a user installation error rather than a package bug, you have mismatched versions installed.  Using a package manager is designed to avoid such issues but you say you are not doing that.

Comment: tlmgr update --list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/user/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/userr/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5713

What does this mean?